# Guice assisted inject with singleton scope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an interface A, and a class B implement A.

However, the constructor of B is looks like:

```
     public class B (C c){}
```

where C is a thrid party library class and can only be created on after the bootstrap.
and I want to B to be a singleton.

I found it difficult to implement this in Guice. I know I can use assisted injector to do this:

```
    public class B (@Assisted C c){}

    public AFactory {
          public A createA(C c);
    }
```

but it looks assisted injector canot produce a singleton instance.

any idea how to implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As you found out, you cannot use assisted inject to create singletons. Assisted inject is for instances that require programmatic parameters and singletons are not created programatically.

**Singletons are constructed lazily** unless you invoke `asEagerSingleton()` on the binding in your module. So you can simply inject C into B and your instance of C will be created after the guice injector has been created. If the creation of C is more involved, create a provider of C and bind it in your module.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Module` you could create an instance of `C` and add it to the context. Then you could annotate class `B` normally.

```
@Singleton
public class B...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but as I said, it is not possible to create C before the bootstrap. It is only created on the fly when application runs, although C is also a Singleton.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by bootstrap. With Guice you control programmatically when a module is configured. So you can programmatically wait till the bootstapping is done, then configure the module that deals with classes B & C.

Comment: Why not code AFactory in old style without assist? Inject the factory with Guice but implement createA by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need Assisted injection here.

Did you think about implementing (and binding) a `Provider<C>`? Then `C` becomes injectable into `B` (and anywhere a `C` is needed).